What are the ethical arguments for the boycotting of the art of morally reprehensible people?
Let's first assume that the profit made from the consumption of the art is not used to perpetuate any of the acts which make the artist morally reprehensible - for example, a rapist in a highly monitored prison. Gaining more money is not going to help them rape more. What are the arguments for the idea that it is immoral to consume their art (including cases in which they profit off of it)? I've seen lots of people suggest that it is immoral. It seems to me that a theory like utilitarianism wouldn't work, and the ethical system would need to incorporate some idea of 'deserving'.

Contemplation of the art implies contemplation of the artist and that's wrong because...

...it is a wrong per se to contemplate evil people without practical need.

...I don't like contemplating evil people. And I define good partially or completely in terms of whether I like things.

...I am concerned that teaching myself to associate my enjoyment of art with my contemplation of evil people will damage my moral sense.



Punishing evil people is a good because...

...it just is.
...I like it. And I define good partially or completely in terms of whether I like things.
...it contributes to a system of incentives and constraints which in aggregate has good consequences.


Benefiting evil people is a wrong because...

...it just is.
...I don't like it. And I define good partially or completely in terms of whether I like things.
...it contributes to a system of incentives and constraints which in aggregate has bad consequences.


Art purchases are approximately zero-sum. Allocating scarce resources to evil people instead of not-evil people is wrong because...

...it just is.
...I don't like it. And I define good partially or completely in terms of whether I like things.
...it contributes to a system of incentives and constraints which in aggregate has bad consequences.


The spelling out of the options is nice. But they all seem to reduce to "good is good", so why not bite the bullet and simply say, "it just is"? Before airplanes were well understood, we might have said that airplane wings work because they just do. From there, we could progress.
